# Generate multiple docs and zip for download

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, aws-amplify

I'm currently using [docx.js](https://docx.js.org/#/) in my react application I have setup with AWS Amplify (node backend). I am generating multiple documents and am saving them separately using the [packer](https://docx.js.org/#/usage/packers) to generate the document as a blob and then use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)'s `saveAs` function to download. See code sample below:

```
const aDoc = new Document();
const bDoc = new Document();
const cDoc = new Document();

// Code that adds content to each doc

// Use packer to generate document as blob and download using FileSaver
Packer.toBlob(aDoc).then((blob) => {
    // saveAs from FileSaver will download the file
    FileSaver(blob, "aDoc.docx");
});
Packer.toBlob(bDoc).then((blob) => {
    // saveAs from FileSaver will download the file
    FileSaver(blob, "bDoc.docx");
});
Packer.toBlob(cDoc).then((blob) => {
    // saveAs from FileSaver will download the file
    FileSaver(blob, "cDoc.docx");
});
```

Now I'm wondering, how can I instead put these all into a ZIP file and have the user download that instead? Haven't really found much around, just [this](https://medium.com/geekculture/updated-how-to-create-multiple-documents-with-docx-js-with-json-data-in-javascript-b1924879b288), which seems more like a workaround as it uses `timeout` to avoid issues when there are many documents--I'd rather avoid that and have it download in an archive instead. I've seen some libraries, like [JSZip](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip) mentioned, but don't really understand how to get what docx.js is giving me into the archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at using JSZip - https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip

I have reworked some code I used within a POC to how I believe it may work with your project and the code above.

```
var JSZip = require('jszip')

const Demo = () => {

    const demoClick = () => {
        var zip = new JSZip()
        const zipFilename = 'test.zip'
        const blobs = []

        Packer.toBlob(aDoc).then((blob) => {
            blobs.push(blob)
        })
        // repeat if needed

        var urlArr = blobs // this will be your set of blobs you are downloading on their own right now.
        urlArr.forEach(function (url) {
            var filename = 'test.docx'

            zip.file(filename, url, { binary: true })
        })

        zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then(function (content) {
            // you may need to work the content into a zip blob like this depending how FileSaver takes it
            const zipContents = URL.createObjectURL(content)
            //or
            const zipContents = new Blob([content], {
                type: 'application/zip'
            })

            // saveAs from FileSaver will download the file
            FileSaver(content, zipFilename)
        })
    }

   return <button onClick={demoClick}>demo</button>
}
```

If FileSaver doesn't like the format of the ZIP you could then use a more simple non imported download/save method

```
const zipContents = URL.createObjectURL(content)
if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(content, zipFilename)
} else if (isIOS && isChrome) {
    window.open(zipContents, '_blank')
} else {
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = zipContents
    link.target = '_blank'
    link.download = zipFilename
    link.click()
}
```

Comment: I apologize it took me so long to get back, but this really helped. only thing I'd add is that I had to use `await` instead of `then()` when generating the blob with the `Packer` as otherwise there would be nothing to actually add to the ZIP archive.